Internal connection fatal error occurs when running ToList
In my business, I call multiple Azure functions in parallel from DataFactory.
If it try to execute ToList at that time, Error occur in the Close() process as shown below.
System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryCloseInternal(Boolean closeReader)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDataReader.Close()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDataReader.Dispose()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.Enumerator.Dispose() 
at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection) 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
at ProcessAndCheck.Activities.CreateTReturnNewSerious.RunActivity(TaskOrchestrationContext context, FunctionContext functionContext) 
in C:\Users\yamaguchi.chieko\Desktop\Next-Generation Quality Management\analysis-source\ProcessAndCheck\Activities\CreateTReturnNewSerious.cs:line 73

I think it's probably the flow from 1 to 3.
If anyone has any knowledge, please let me know.

Another Azure function is starting to query the DB
Perform ToList when 1 is not finished (query to DB is executed)
Internal connection fatal error because other processes are not closed

Also, in this case, I was thinking about using asynchronous processing (ToListAsync) as a countermeasure.
Do you think it would be effective?
I would like to hear from you if there is any effective method.

Any asynchronous methods such as ToListAsync should solve the error, they make sure the connections are released safely.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
